# Confused about x/y when extruding along normals in Python

Tags: python, normals, extrude

I'm a 3D newbie but I have programming experience. I'm using Blender 2.91.0 on Linux.

I am trying to write a script to create a path/road from JSON data. The general strategy is to start from a block, and then extrude the "forward-facing" face for each item in the `track_data` list (this script only goes up and down, no curves). My problem comes from that extrusion: when using `"orient_type": "NORMAL"` I know that in this context "z" is the normal itself, but I don't seem to have a reliable way to tell which one of x or y points up (global "z"). What is even weirder is that it seems to change according to the value of the extrusion.

I have been able to produce a reduced test case that shows what I'm talking about:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import bpy
import bmesh

# Cut off point is around 1.1945 ????
MULTIPLIER = 1

track_data = [
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": 0}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": 0}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": 0,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -6.041601,}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": -6.041601,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -24.154236,}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": -24.154236,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -54.301429,}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": -54.301429,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -96.422468,}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": -96.422468,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -150.432527,}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": -150.432527,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -216.222836,}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": -216.222836,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -293.660902,}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": -293.660902,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -382.590776,}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": -382.590776,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -482.833365,}}}
]

# Initial segment
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
cube = bpy.context.object
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(6, 4, 5))
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 0, -4.95))

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')


for segment in track_data:
    altitude_diff = (segment["p2"]["world"]["y"] - segment["p1"]["world"]["y"]) / 400

    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(cube.data)
    bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
    for face in bm.faces:
        face.select = False
    # Select the forward-looking face. Hacky, but seems reliable enough.
    forward_face = bm.faces[-5] if len(bm.faces) <= 6 else bm.faces[-4]
    forward_face.select = True

    extrusion = (0, altitude_diff * MULTIPLIER, 2)
    bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(
        TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":extrusion, "orient_type":"NORMAL"}
    )

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

If you run that script, the result will be the first image (the "y" coordinate is the global "x" so it turns left). If you change the `MULTIPLIER` constant at the top to `2`, the result will be the second image (the "y" coordinate is the global "z", so it goes down... which is what I what).

[image: Result when MULTIPLIER=1. The road turns left]
[image: Result when MULTIPLIER=2. The road turns down]

So, is there any way to make sure that x or y in that extrusion is consistently "pointing up" (in my case it will always literally be global z)? I am not doing any rotations in this script, and the full script will only use rotations on the z axis (for curves).

I have tried playing a bit with other parameters to `TRANSFORM_OT_translate`, like `orient_matrix`, but I don't know what to try and I cannot find documentation anywhere.

**EDIT:** I realised that I will only be rotating for curves (not shown in this script) so the question is a bit simpler, because *I am* looking for the global z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bmesh take on this.**

*IMO would step straight into API methods using linear algebra, and bmesh for operating on mesh ASAP.  ... no mode toggling mind boggling mesh operators, ...*

Have used question script to add the initial cube, then from there gone object mode bmesh

- Transformed (translate and scale) the mesh using matrices.
- Given all six faces names Y is north, Z is up.
- Then chosen to "go west". This is travel 2 in direction of west face
  normal, and up by elevation difference each step.
- Totally confused as to MULTIPLIER and its cut off point, so left it
  out.

Test script, goes west.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix
# Cut off point is around 1.1945 ????
MULTIPLIER = 1

track_data = [
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": 0}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": 0}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": 0,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -6.041601,}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": -6.041601,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -24.154236,}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": -24.154236,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -54.301429,}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": -54.301429,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -96.422468,}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": -96.422468,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -150.432527,}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": -150.432527,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -216.222836,}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": -216.222836,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -293.660902,}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": -293.660902,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -382.590776,}}},
    {"p1": {"world": {"y": -382.590776,}}, "p2": {"world": {"y": -482.833365,}}}
]

step = 2

# Initial segment
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
cube = bpy.context.object
me = cube.data

M = (
    Matrix.Translation((0, 0, -4.95)) @
    Matrix.Diagonal((6, 4, 5)).to_4x4() 
    ) 
me.transform(M)
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

west, north, east, south, down, up = bm.faces

go = west

for segment in track_data:
    altitude_diff = (segment["p2"]["world"]["y"] - segment["p1"]["world"]["y"]) / 400
    go = bmesh.ops.extrude_discrete_faces(
        bm,
        faces=[go],
        )["faces"].pop()
    bmesh.ops.translate(
        bm,
        vec=step * go.normal + altitude_diff * up.normal,
        verts=go.verts,
        )
bm.to_mesh(me)
me.update()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm surprised that the order of faces is consistent, similar things have felt pretty random to me, even as in "different every time I run the same, unmodified script".

The `MULTIPLIER` is what I mentioned in my question: changing the amount to extrude by changes what x and y point to! The cutoff is when the change happens: values under the cutoff point seem to always behave the same; same with values over it.

Comment: BTW it seems that the `bmesh.ops.translate` call should be inside the loop. At least that's how I made it work. I cannot edit the answer to correct it because SE wants me to modify more than just four characters 